# Error Laravel Input:get route web

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, input

I have to ask something again. Here is my java script code

```
<script>
    $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var spielID = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('/spieler-table?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){

            //success data
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine.
But in my route web there I getting an error.

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/spieler-table?spielID=3 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here it is...

```
Route::get('/spieler-table', function(){
    $testvar = Input::get('spielID');
    echo $testvar;
});
```

I think it is because of the var spielID which comes from my javascript code.
Because the i get into the Route get and the php echo works fine with an easy string output. But when I try to Input the spielID into tester. I getting the error. Im using the laravel framework

Comment: Open error logs and read detail error description.

Comment: Where I can find the error logs?

Comment: Go to http://localhost:8000/spieler-table?spielID=3 to see the errors. If you can't see any errors but just "500 error" or smt. edit your .env file and set DEBUG to true. If still can't see the errors try setting display_errors to on in your php.ini. Your application logs are under `storage/logs`

Answer (score 0):

change your script little bit :

```
<script>
        $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){


            var spielID = $('#spiele').val();

            //ajax
            $.get('/spieler-table?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){

                //success data
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

change your route code like this :

```
Route::get('/spieler-table', function(Request $request){
        $testvar = $request->spielID;
        return $testvar;
    });
```